# Why doesn't Mathematica automatically use symbolic sums?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why doesn't Mathematica automatically use symbolic sums to make computations faster? For instance, the following code takes a very long time to execute.

```
    fr[r_] := PDF[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 10}], r];
    Sum[fr[r], {r, 1, 100000000000000000000000000000}]
```

If I replace the last line with the following, the computation is instantaneous.

```
    ReplaceRepeated[Sum[fr[r], {r, 1, n}], n -> 100000000000000000000000000000]
```

Is there a way to automatically compute the sum in a symbolic manner?

Comment: I think even in the first case, Mathematica eventually did the sum symbolically; otherwise it won't finish within Earth's lifetime!

Comment: Haha perhaps the following is a better example that seems to take an extremely long time. It seems Mathematica actually did compute my original post symbolically. Maybe since it was a large enough input.

`Sum[fr[r], {r, 1, 10000000000000000}]`

Comment: Perhaps because most times it can't find a symbolic result, and even if it does it is not always faster, nor gives the correct result as often as the explicit sum? This is documented, and you already seem to have a way to compute it symbolically first, right?